# App Engine and Google Drive API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have been working with the app engine for a few weeks and now I am trying to do something new. I would like to display a list of an users newest 25 documents. But I am not sure how to go about this. Could someone point me to some information ?

I have a application setup that:
1. That can use the Google Drive API
2. User have to login to use the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are full GAE application examples for [Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python) and [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java) in the [Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

Then inspect the [files:list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) of the api.

Comment: Python and Java link are 404s. Actual example in SO would have been better.

Comment: @guiomie can you provide links ?