# Read all files in a directory from inside Google App Engine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-io

I understand that Google App Engine (GAE) allows you to read any file inside the exploded WAR using several methods like:

```
String file = "/WEB-INF/name-of-my-filexml";
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

The problem is, I need to deploy my web app with a directory structure like this:

```
MyApp/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        classes/
        web.xml
        appengine-web.xml
        ...

        profiles/
            fizz.txt
            buzz.txt
            foo.txt
            ... dozens of other text files
```

I need a way to read each `profiles/*.txt` file into a Java string. And before anyone comments **well why not just hardcode the strings, dude...**, let's just say that I'm cutting out a lot of backstory here for the sake of posting a simple question. Humor me, and let's pretend I cannot hardcode the strings. Normally, if I had full access to `java.io.*`, I'd just do something like:

```
File profilesHome = new File("path/to/profiles");
File[] profiles = profilesHome.listFiles();
List<String> profileList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(File profile : profiles)
    profileList.add(readFileIntoString(profile));
```

But here, I don't think I can invoke `File#listFiles()`, and if all I have is the `InputStream` that I get back from `getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)`, I'm not sure how to turn that into a `File` handle or String object. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** using `ZipInputStream` suggestion:

```
InputStream inputStream = event.getServletContext()
        .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/profiles.zip");
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ZipEntry currEntry;
try {
    while((currEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
        // TODO: How to convert the contents of currEntry to a string
        // in a manner that is GAE-friendly?
        list.add(convertEntryContentsToString(currEntry));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, **how do I implement `convertEntryContentsToString(ZipEntry)`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code snippet can help you (maybe you'll have to add some exception handling, closing code, some other stuff, ...):

```
while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String name = zipEntry.getName();
    if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(zipStream);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        String YOURSTRING = builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the following options work for you:

1. Create a file named `filelist.txt`, which is also present in the `WEB-INF/profiles` folder or any other folder starting from `wEB-INF`. This file can contain a list of file names present in the `/profiles` folder. One file name on each line. This way you can parse the name out one by one and then read the files.
2. Create a datastore entity that contains a list of file names that you expect and follow the same steps as 1, except that the list of file names is got from a datastore entity.
3. Is Google Drive (see this [App Engine and Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185504/app-engine-and-google-drive-api)) an option for you? Another option is Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put every .txt into a single Zip-File you can use ZipInputStream and ZipEntry to list all files in the Zip-File (or access them directly if you want).

Comment: Thanks @da_re (+1) - please see my update at the bottom of the original question. Yes, I can zip everything up into `/WEB-INF/profiles.zip`. Now I'm just struggling to convert each `ZipEntry` (which is a *.txt file) into a java String using readers that are "GAE-friendly" (that is, aren't restricted by the sandbox). Any ideas? Thanks again, immensely!